# Python- Turning a 2D list of strings into a 2D list of characters

Tags: string, list, split, char, 2d

I have a 2d list that is as follows:

```
[['qwe'],['asd'],['zxc']]
```

I would like to turn this into a 2d list of characters like this:

```
[['q','w','e,'], ['a','s','d'],['z','x','c']]
```

This seems like a fairly simple problem, however the only methods I may use are split(),join() and strip(). I tried to use split, however I ran into problems since this involves a 2d list.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension for this case without any of the methods you mentioned. The main thing in the code is to make sure you are passing the [0] for each value in the 2D list:

```
a = [['qwe'],['asd'],['zxc']]
b = [list(i[0]) for i in a]
```

Output:

```
[['q', 'w', 'e'], ['a', 's', 'd'], ['z', 'x', 'c']]
```